# forcefully open a browsers on a network pc using the cmd

Tags: cmd

I would like to forcefully open a browsers on a network pc using the cmd on windows 10 for example - start chrome "webpage" On Ipddress of target pc (not my own)

Comment: is wmi enabled on the target pc?

Comment: yes it is just checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
wmic /node:"targethostname" /user:"Administrator" /password:"***"  
   process call create "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe www.example.com"
```

Comment: If you use domains you have to specify the username by `/user:"MYDOMAIN\Administrator"`

Comment: something similar without having to know the targets password ?

Comment: @J.Alex **No way!** Even if there is a way to do this, I wont never ever tell anyone how to do this!

Comment: fair play wanted to play around with a mate of mine and spam websites at him

Comment: accepted as answer as useful if you know the passwords